# Binding Source vs x:Static

Tags: wpf, binding, properties, static

in WPF one can bind to static properties. Now I know 2 ways of doing this:

```
Content="{x:Static stat:Statics.CurrentUser}"
```

Or:

```
Content="{Binding Source={x:Static stat:Statics.CurrentUser}}"
```

Are there any differences between these 2 methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Main difference in this case is that `x:Static` does not perform additional conversion

From [`x:Static Markup Extension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Use caution when you make x:Static references that are not directly the type of a property's value. In the XAML processing sequence, **provided values from a markup extension do not invoke additional value conversion**. This is true even if your x:Static reference creates a text string, and a value conversion for attribute values based on text string typically occurs either for that specific member or for any member values of the return type.

So lets say you do

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}"/>
```

this will cause runtime error:

> '#FFB4B4B4' is not a valid value for property 'Text'.

because `SolidColorBrush` is not `String` whilst

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}}"/>
```

will work fine and display *#FFB4B4B4* because it will perform `ToString()` conversion. Also without `Binding` you are not able to access instance properties of static object so for example you would not be able to get `Color` property of that brush

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}, Path=Color}"/>
```