# Performance impact: Binding Source vs x:Static

Tags: wpf, xaml, properties, binding, static

Is there a noticeable impact on performance if I setup the binding this way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}}/>
```

instead of this way:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}"/>
```

?

Or do I have to expect other drawbacks?

The difference is already described here: [Binding Source vs x:Static](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24221001/2780989). But there is no statement about the performance impact/drawbacks.

Comment: does 2nd example work at all? linked post says it will cause runtime error. Exception is a serious drawback, isn't it?

Comment: Good point. Maybe the copied example is not that good. But my question is more if it generally can cause problems. A better example is something like this:
"... Label="{Binding Source={x:Static oc:LocalizedText.Data}}" ..."
instead of 
"... Label="{x:Static oc:LocalizedText.Data}" ..."

Comment: @Jean-Claude, additional difference between Binding Source vs x:Static: binding can be TwoWay (since .net 4.5, example shown here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/31611110/1506454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a *noticeable* impact on performance if I setup the binding this way?

No, there isn't provided that the static property actually returns a value that the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` can be set to of course :)

In other words there is no non-negligible performance difference between doing this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}}" Text="Test"/>
```

...and this:

```
<TextBlock Foreground="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}" Text="Test"/>
```

`x:Static` is probably theoretically faster since it doesn't perform any conversion but this is pretty much negligible on a 2017 era computer I would say.